# Leaflet.js and working with geoJSON loaded form file

Tags: javascript, leaflet

After creating a map using leaflet.js and then loading a geoJSON layer, I am trying to add a popup to each feature when clicked - the examples I can find all assume the geoJSON added inline, but I load mine from a file (which I would have thought more common, but anyway..) and I can't get it to work.

I know the geoJSON is OK, because I have this working using Google Maps, but I want to try and do this using Leaflet.js

The below will load the geoJSON layer if I don't attempt the "onEachFeature" call

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([55.505, -0.09], 7);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href=”http://osm.org/copyright”>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('[path-to-geoJSON-file]');

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  if (feature.properties && feature.properties.name) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
  }
}

L.geoJSON(geojsonLayer, {
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);

//  commewnt out above block and the below works to just load the layer
geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
```

[edit] as Grzegorz T. has kindly pointed out, this "looks correct as much as I can say", and indeed it does work if I load the geoJSON directly into the geojsonLayer var, either via code-behind or a vanilla ajax call, so the issue with the above is clearly something to do with the GeoJSON.AJAX plugin, which is somehow not loading the geoJSON in quite the way the rest of leaflet expects. If anyone has any ideas I'd be nterested, but am happy enough not using the plugin.

Comment: L.GeoJSON.AJAX is not part of leaflejs but a separate library leaflet-ajax.  You should create a minimal example with the geojson sample and the libraries you use. Because how can I guess what the geojson looks like? And the most important thing, I recommend that you check the leaflet documentation.

Comment: Does it matter what the geojson looks like? It's valid, and the "features" include a property called "name" - as I said, I can load this same file into Google Maps (Data Layers) and it works fine. Would it make a difference if I load it via a vanilla JS (or JQuery)  Ajax call instead? Of course I've looked at the documentation, that's what got me as far as I have - it gives examples of clickable "features" for geojson loaded via a string - all I want is the same thing but loaded from a file. Why is there, and what is, the difference?

Comment: Instead of writing so much, you would spend this time preparing a working example with a small geojson sample and put it on jsfiddle.net, codepen.io or codesandbox.io
Still nothing comes from the code you put in. It looks correct as much as I can say.

Comment: "It looks correct as much as I can say" - is what I wanted to hear :) See my edit, and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet the documentation has not been read. Not only the leaflet but also L.GeoJSON.Ajax had to be looked into.
Not only is it described nicely and there are examples, laziness ;)

Just change `nazwa` to `name`
because i used a different geojson file

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([52.22977, 21.01178], 7);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href=”http://osm.org/copyright”>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  if (feature.properties && feature.properties.nazwa) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.nazwa);
  }
}

const geojson = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ppatrzyk/polska-geojson/master/wojewodztwa/wojewodztwa-min.geojson';

let jsonTest = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(geojson, {
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

If you do not use jquery and you do not need to run this code on IE, I recommend another solution, i.e. using fetch, take a look at my [example](https://tomik23.github.io/leaflet-examples/#15.geoJson-simple)

Comment: Yeah ok, thanks - I decided it was actually just as easy to avoid that ajax library anyway in the end :)